# In app purchase with hosted content does not work when live

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

Recently I have published application with in-app purchase to App Store. In-app purchase contains hosted content. This purchase item was fully tested with sandbox users and with beta testers as well. But when we go live this item does not work. Payments for this purchase was withdrawn, but content is still locked. I can fetch selected product and his price in App Store build.

Also, I am wondering that all works great using sandbox user, works for all beta and internal testers, but does not work in app downloaded from App Store. This even works after switching back to sandbox.

In-app purchase is approved, content inside is valid, application is ready for sale.

Are there some differences between in-app purchase configuration for App Store build and TestFlight/installed from Xcode one?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an issue on Apple's servers that started a few days ago. See this forum thread:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80546

Apple's server team is said to be addressing it now. Here's a quote from an Apple staff member on that thread:

"I've forwarded all of these bug reports to the Apps Ops Engineering QA team for thei review. For everyone else, by all means submit bug reports, but at this point, I'm not going verify that the bug reports are passed on to Apps Ops Engineering QA. The server team's attention is now on this issue."

Comment: Seems it is working now. Thanks, your suggestion was right.